# WinSCP command-line passive mode

Tags: scripting, ftp, winscp, passive-mode

I am calling WinSCP via command line but I can't figure out how to set passive mode properly to the script.

Here is the script now:

```
 option batch on
 option confirm off

 open ftp://user_and_pass_details:21
 cd /out/

 option transfer binary
 put C:\afile.text

 close
 exit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the passive option in your open:

```
open ftp://user_and_pass_details:21 -passive=on|off
```

Your full script will become:

```
 option batch on

 option confirm off

 open ftp://user_and_pass_details:21 -passive=on

 cd /out/

 option transfer binary

 put C:\afile.text

 close

 exit
```

Please refer to: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open
(anyway, note that by default, the passive mode is active: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_connection#connection)

Comment: Thanks - that was the answer I was looking for.  I think in older versions of Winscp the passive mode was not default but I could be wrong.  We also upgraded to the latest version and things are running smooth.

Comment: You are right, it has been added in the `5.0.2 beta` (http://winscp.net/tracker/show_bug.cgi?id=165)