# Delete from a remote FTP site using PASV from the command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I have a program that can launch batch files (.bat) and I need to write a batch file to delete all files from an FTP directory.

My first try was the windows ftp command line program, batch file was:

```
ftp -i -s:ftpscript.txt
```

With the script being:

```
open ftp.hostname.com
myusername
mypassword
quote pasv
binary
cd In
mdelete *.txt
quit
```

After trying this for a while I found the ftp program doesn't support passive mode... great!

Next I tried ncftp but I can't find any commands that can delete without downloading files.

**Question**

Is there any way to either:

get ftp windows command working under passive mode?
make ncftp delete all remote files in a directory?
use any other command line program (in windows) which will support passive mode and delete an entire directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another utility which worked perfectly WinSCP.

Also referenced this script:

[WinSCP command-line passive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470080/winscp-command-line-passive-mode)